# __main__ module not found in em package while installing ROS

Tags: python, ros

I am trying to install ROS Noetic. I am stuck at the "catkin_make install" step. While trying to execute the above command, I am getting the following error.

command line `catkin_make`

The error that I am getting

```
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/noetic;/home/anant/ros2_foxy/install/yaml_cpp_vendor;/home/anant/ros2_foxy/install/ament_cmake_uncrustify;/home/anant/ros2_foxy/install/uncrustify_vendor;/home/anant/ros2_foxy/install/tracetools;/home/anant/ros2_foxy/install/tinyxml2_vendor;/home/anant/ros2_foxy/install/qt_gui;/home/anant/ros2_foxy/install/tango_icons_vendor;/home/anant/ros2_foxy/install/spdlog_vendor;/home/anant/ros2_foxy/install/rosidl_typesupport_interface;/home/anant/ros2_foxy/install/rosidl_generator_dds_idl;/home/anant/ros2_foxy/install/rosidl_cmake;/home/anant/ros2_foxy/install/rosidl_parser;/home/anant/ros2_foxy/install/rosidl_adapter;/home/anant/ros2_foxy/install/rmw_implementation_cmake;/home/anant/ros2_foxy/install/python_qt_binding;/home/anant/ros2_foxy/install/launch_testing_ament_cmake;/home/anant/ros2_foxy/install/python_cmake_module;/home/anant/ros2_foxy/install/osrf_testing_tools_cpp;/home/anant/ros2_foxy/install/ament_cmake_ros;/home/anant/ros2_foxy/install/ament_cmake_gmock;/home/anant/ros2_foxy/install/gmock_vendor;/home/anant/ros2_foxy/install/ament_cmake_gtest;/home/anant/ros2_foxy/install/gtest_vendor;/home/anant/ros2_foxy/install/ament_cmake_google_benchmark;/home/anant/ros2_foxy/install/google_benchmark_vendor;/home/anant/ros2_foxy/install/foonathan_memory_vendor;/home/anant/ros2_foxy/install/fastrtps_cmake_module;/home/anant/ros2_foxy/install/fastcdr;/home/anant/ros2_foxy/install/eigen3_cmake_module;/home/anant/ros2_foxy/install/cyclonedds;/home/anant/ros2_foxy/install/connext_cmake_module;/home/anant/ros2_foxy/install/ament_cmake_xmllint;/home/anant/ros2_foxy/install/ament_cmake_pep257;/home/anant/ros2_foxy/install/ament_lint_auto;/home/anant/ros2_foxy/install/ament_cmake;/home/anant/ros2_foxy/install/ament_cmake_version;/home/anant/ros2_foxy/install/ament_cmake_pytest;/home/anant/ros2_foxy/install/ament_cmake_lint_cmake;/home/anant/ros2_foxy/install/ament_cmake_flake8;/home/anant/ros2_foxy/install/ament_cmake_cpplint;/home/anant/ros2_foxy/install/ament_cmake_cppcheck;/home/anant/ros2_foxy/install/ament_cmake_copyright;/home/anant/ros2_foxy/install/ament_cmake_test;/home/anant/ros2_foxy/install/ament_cmake_target_dependencies;/home/anant/ros2_foxy/install/ament_cmake_python;/home/anant/ros2_foxy/install/ament_cmake_export_dependencies;/home/anant/ros2_foxy/install/ament_cmake_libraries;/home/anant/ros2_foxy/install/ament_cmake_include_directories;/home/anant/ros2_foxy/install/ament_cmake_export_targets;/home/anant/ros2_foxy/install/ament_cmake_export_link_flags;/home/anant/ros2_foxy/install/ament_cmake_export_interfaces;/home/anant/ros2_foxy/install/ament_cmake_export_libraries;/home/anant/ros2_foxy/install/ament_cmake_export_include_directories;/home/anant/ros2_foxy/install/ament_cmake_export_definitions;/home/anant/ros2_foxy/install/ament_cmake_core;/home/anant/ros2_foxy/install/ament_index_cpp
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/noetic
-- Found PythonInterp: /home/anant/anaconda3/bin/python3 (found suitable version "3.8.5", minimum required is "3") 
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /home/anant/anaconda3/bin/python3
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /home/anant/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/em
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/anant/catkin_ws/src/test_results
-- Forcing gtest/gmock from source, though one was otherwise available.
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/googletest': gtests will be built
-- Found gmock sources under '/usr/src/googletest': gmock will be built
-- Found PythonInterp: /home/anant/anaconda3/bin/python3 (found version "3.8.5") 
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests3
-- catkin 0.8.9
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
/home/anant/anaconda3/bin/python3: can't find '__main__' module in '/home/anant/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/em'
CMake Error at /opt/ros/noetic/share/catkin/cmake/safe_execute_process.cmake:11 (message):
  execute_process(/home/anant/catkin_ws/src/catkin_generated/env_cached.sh
  "/home/anant/anaconda3/bin/python3"
  "/home/anant/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/em" "--raw-errors" "-F"
  "/home/anant/catkin_ws/src/catkin_generated/order_packages.py" "-o"
  "/home/anant/catkin_ws/src/catkin_generated/order_packages.cmake"
  "/opt/ros/noetic/share/catkin/cmake/em/order_packages.cmake.em") returned
  error code 1
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/noetic/share/catkin/cmake/em_expand.cmake:25 (safe_execute_process)
  /opt/ros/noetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_workspace.cmake:35 (em_expand)
  CMakeLists.txt:69 (catkin_workspace)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/anant/catkin_ws/src/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/anant/catkin_ws/src/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

link to the tutorial I am following
http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/commands/catkin_make

It would be very helpful if someone could help me in this regards
Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: hey Anant Garg, Could you paste your code instead of a screenshot? That makes it easier for people to read your question and more likely you get an answer.

Comment: Hello Jonas, I have made the necessary edits to my question. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem because I have `anaconda` installed.
The catkin was looking for the package in: `/home/leandro/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/`

after uninstalling them from the current and `sudo` users with
`pip uninstall em empy` and
`sudo pip uninstall em empy`

`catkin` was able to find the correct `em` and `empy` packages at `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/em.py`

I am afraid there is an nice spaghetti in my system right now, but the catkin works.